# Indexing .png/JPG/PDF files in elastic search from fileserver

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, elastic-stack

Am having search based requirement. Am able to do indexing oracle database tables into elasticsearch by using logstash. In the same way, i have to index png/JPG/PDF files which are all presented in fileserver now.

Am using elasticsearch version 6.2.3. Can anyone have any idea about indexing files from fileserver to elasticsearch ?

purpose - why am seeing for indexing png/JPG/PDF :

1. i have to search and display some products with product information, along with that i have to display product picture also which is stored in fileserver.
2. I have a feature to search for documents (pdf). so,if is search with any keywords, it should also search in the contents of the documents and bring those document as search results.  Here documents filepath is available in DB only files are available in fileserver.

For these two purpose, am looking for indexing png/JPG/PDF files.

Comment: What is the purpose of indexing binary data? Do you intend to index their location/path/url?

Comment: @Val - i have updated my question with the purpose for why am looking for indexing binary data.

Comment: Can you post a typical query that you expect? To me it sounds like all you need to do is store the file paths relative to the fileserver and do some client side processing to make these visible to the user. If you absolutely must then checkout https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest-attachment.html which is based on Apache Tika which supports https://tika.apache.org/0.9/formats.html

Answer (score 0):

You just have to get bytes from your image(you can do it in any program language) and then save them in field with [binary](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/binary.html) type. But it is not a good idea, try to save the link to the image.